# UIActivityIndicatorView animation delayed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I work on an application with some heavy tasks (Ajax requests and JSON parsing) and I'd like to use UIIndicatorViews to show the device is busy.

Let's say I start from a "source" view and want to show an indicator before going on a "target" view after having loaded my data.

My approach: starting the indicator in source.didSelectRowAtPath, loading the data in target.viewDidLoad, stopping the indicator in source.viewDidDisappear.

Problem: the indicator animates only after a delay.

"Source.m"

```
- (void)startIndicator {
   indicator.hidden = NO;
   [indicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)stopIndicator {
   indicator.hidden = YES;
   [indicator stopAnimating];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   [self stopIndicator];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   [self stopIndicator];
   [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

"Target"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self longLoadingMethod];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had to use **detachNewThreadSelector** to start the indicator in an other thread!

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(stopIndicator)
                            toTarget:self
                          withObject:nil];
   // instead of [self stopIndicator];
}
```

**Edit**

And to start Indicator:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startIndicator)
                            toTarget:self
                          withObject:nil];

// instead of [self startIndicator];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not trigger the loading on the user action (the action that would trigger the transition)?

1. User taps the `UIResponder` Loading begins in background (current VC is a
   delegate or use a completion block)
2. Activity indicator activated
   (make sure this happens on the main thread)
3. When loading completes,
   hide activity indicator, transition views

This can all be done without messing around with NSThread -- also if you fail to load perhaps you don't want to transition views (maybe to show an alert instead?).

**EDIT**

You could do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)didTapLoadResource:(id)sender
{
    [self startIndicator];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:self.remoteResource queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        [self stopIndicator];
        if (error)
        {
            [self showFailureAlert];
        }
        else
        {
            [self presentViewController:self.loadedVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }];
}
```

*Note that this code was written in the browser and may need editing.*

Comment: **New try** with a start in didSelectRowAtPath but the delay's still there. I thought it was called right after the click on the cell. Am I wrong? How can I detect a click otherwise? Thanks!

Comment: didSelectRowAtPath should get called right away and you can make the threadStartAnimating call synchronously from the main thread. Is that what you're doing now?

Comment: DidSelectRowAtPath is indeed the first method called. But with or without detachNewThreadSelector, still the delay. I've heard about performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:, but don't see how I could use it between two views...

Comment: Maybe I'm a little confused about your UI. You have **UIView A**, you start an asynchronous network load, you show a spinner over **UIView A** (yes?), when network load completes you stop spinner and transition to **UIView B**. Is this accurate?

Comment: This is accurate. Should I display the activity indicator on the UIViewB?

Comment: @debrax I edited my answer to illustrate my suggestion. I put it in the context of a button press, but you could as easily call it from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` (or perhaps `willSelectRowAtIndexPath`)

Comment: I don't know what was wrong, but after a lot of other changes to the file, detachNewThreadSelector now works. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If your indicator is a UIActivityIndicator, you should make sure it happens on the main thread. UIKit behavior is not guaranteed on other threads.